# Unable to change variant image when option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I have an on change function that is supposed to change the image to the selected variant image, but i cannot get this working. Here is the html markup;

```
            {% for image in product.images %}
              <div class="single-product-image single-option-selector" {% if image.attached_to_variant? %} data-variant="{{ image.variants.first.id }}"{% endif %} style="{% if forloop.index > 1 %}display:none;{% endif %}">
                <img class="img-fluid lazyload"
                     src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1200x1200', crop: 'center' }}"
                     data-src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1200x1200', crop: 'center' }}"
                     alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

This is the option selector used to pick the variant from Shopify

```
        <select name="{{option_name}}" id="select-{{option_name}}" class="js-variant-id-image">
          <option class="js-variant-radio" value="placeholder" disabled {% if selected == false %}selected{% endif %}>Select {{ option.name }}</option>
            {% for value in option.values %}
              <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == selected %}selected{% endif %} {% for variant in product.variants %} data-inventory-quantity="{{ variant.inventory_quantity }}"{% endfor %}>{{value}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

And here is the jquery function that is supposed to change the image

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.js-variant-id-image', function(){
      let
        variant_id = this.value,
        variant_image = $('.single-product-image[data-variant="'+variant_id+'"]');

        console.log(variant_id);

      variant_image.show().siblings(":visible").hide();
    })
  });
```

Comment: Please provide samples of the source html sent to browser, without the server side templating. We have no way to run this otherwise to see the problem. See [mcve]

Comment: which Shopify theme used over the website?

Comment: I am building the theme from scratch

Comment: Okay, so you build using it timber framework or own custom? if you using optin_selection.js from Shopify there is an event called `onVariantChange`, this event returns the data regarding the selected variant and you can use it to check the data and append it to the featured image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$(".single-product-image").not(variant_image).hide()` to hide all divs which doesn't have same data-variant value . Also , make sure `value` of option and value of `data-variant` are same.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('change', '.js-variant-id-image', function() {
  let
    variant_id = this.value,
    variant_image = $('.single-product-image[data-variant="' + variant_id + '"]');
  variant_image.show()
  //get all single div except the one which we need to show hide it
  $(".single-product-image").not(variant_image).hide()
})
```

```css
.single-product-image {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="{{option_name}}" id="select-{{option_name}}" class="js-variant-id-image">
  <option class="js-variant-radio" value="placeholder" disabled selected>Select one</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="single-product-image single-option-selector" data-variant="1" style="">1
  <img class="img-fluid lazyload" src="abc.png" data-src="1" alt="1">
</div>
<div class="single-product-image single-option-selector" data-variant="2" style="">2
  <img class="img-fluid lazyload" src="abc.png" data-src="1" alt="2">
</div>
<div class="single-product-image single-option-selector" data-variant="3" style="">3
  <img class="img-fluid lazyload" src="abc.png" data-src="1" alt="3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @swati for taking the time to respond. The value of the option is passed in via Shopify ```{% for value in option.values %} <option value="{{ value }}"></option>{% endfor %}```and the variant image passed like so; ```{% if image.attached_to_variant? %} data-variant="{{ image.variants.first.id }}"{% endif %}.``` I am not sure how to connect this as suggested.

Comment: is there anything common between `option.values` and `product.images` ? you can use that